# How to display multiple prices on e-commerce?

Tags: e-commerce, prices

At my eCommerce site, I need to show 5 different price information. And is difficult to think different as I have already tried some alternatives.

I need to show -

- "was/old price" [RRP (suggested by industry)]
- the saved amount
- the main price per item and specify that is per item
- the price per m2 and specify it and I need to be clear that the price included VAT

My current solution is this, but I'm not fully happy.
[image]

Any other good idea?

See full block where the price is just and component.

[image]

Comment: I think you should add some context, at least visual. Any option is valid, in fact in your example it's not known why there's a price on the left and another on the right when they could all be in a single column.

Comment: @Danielillo I edited the post to add the print screen of a section where I'm displaying the price.

Comment: I just trying to understand why people downvote an absolutely valid question to discuss user experience in a user experience community. I believe if people that are not capable to answer should skip and go to an easier question.

Comment: Not me but I'd guess the question is too broad or opinion based - the _best way_ will be different depending on the situation or who you ask. Also perhaps because discussions and idea gathering don't fit much with the Q&A model, you can check [ask] for more info.

Comment: As said, at the moment every answer could be valid. Who are your users? Roofing tiles are not your everyday household items. This seems to be an online retail but for whom? What is wrong with your current design, why aren't you "fully happy" about it?

Comment: @locationunknown I would like some alternative to how to display all the information about the price. The print screen is just to understand where the price block is displayed.

Comment: @Luciano I understand your point but is just the same question as a lot of other we find here. I think this can generate a healthy discussion and in UX the most part of thing don't have the right answer. The most part is just alternatives because depend on product, users, environment and seasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Here sam logic behind]

Here is some logic behind;

1. Logical object should be grouped together.. On your site now rrp price to left heading, is same distance as normal price left to rrp.. Price info is one block and should be grouped together
2. When you display old price > new price > saving in %, in a flow, it looks like calculation and user understands it better
3. It is more appropriate to communicate saving in green than in red color, as it is positive thing, and green is already associated with success or action
4. RRP and PER ITEM... are all markings / meta info so I suggest same position and styling for them

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

try Baymard institute:

https://baymard.com/blog/price-per-unit

This answers your question.

Comment: Answers should have enough information in them to answer a question _without_ having to visit links (in case the site dies, or the page is taken down).

Comment: And I'm not looking for a multiple options. I just need to show a unique option but I have too much information in a single space.